# How to use google tag manager with gatsby

Tags: reactjs, google-tag-manager, gatsby

I'm using gatsby and the gatsby-plugin-tag-manager and I'm having trouble getting custom events to trigger. My gatsby-config.js looks like this:

```
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager`,
      options: {
        id: 'GTM-XXXXXXX',
        includeInDevelopment: true,
        defaultDataLayer: function() {
          return {
            pageType: window.pageType,
            // platform: 'gatsby',
          }
        },
      },
```

When I run everything locally, I can get my events to trigger properly using this code:

```
window.dataLayer.push({
  event: 'gatsby-course-splash-sign-up',
})
```

The problem is that when I deploy it *statically* to an s3 bucket instead of running on a server, while the page views trigger, nothing else does. Does anyone know how to get custom triggers to work? Thanks!

Comment: did you manage to solve this?

Comment: I would be interested in this as well.